# Select Case value not sorting correctly in order by

Tags: sql, select

I have a result set that has a defined grouping (for a report). There is a possibility that the position is not assigned and therefore does not have a "Grid_Group". In this case I assign a value of 99. This is working correctly except the order by, the 99 is always first and it should be last (If I do desc it is at bottom). I've tried a cast on the select side as well as within the order by on the Grid_Group, but both have same results with 99 at the top. (Sql server 2008)

Here is the snippet, I remove all other unneeded columns.

```
SELECT s.SessionNumber,Position.PositionName,(Select CASE when dbo.Position.Grid_Group is null THEN 99 ELSE dbo.Position.Grid_Group END) as Grid_Group 
             FROM dbo.USession AS us Left Outer JOIN  
                     dbo.Position ON us.PositionId = dbo.Position.PositionId FULL OUTER JOIN  
                     dbo.Sessions AS s ON us.SessionId = s.SessionId  
                     ORDER BY S.SessionNumber, dbo.Position.Grid_Group
```

Thoughts?

Comment: But there's no CTE to apply the 99, nor is your `CASE` in the `ORDER BY`. So it's probably ordering on the NULL. BTW you can use [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) rather than writing your own case to specify a default-if-null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `CASE` on your order by as well (bear in mind this will ruin index utilization on the sort operation). Your `ORDER BY` is referencing the original table's column, not your alias result column. Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    s.SessionNumber,Position.PositionName,
    (CASE
        WHEN dbo.Position.Grid_Group IS NULL THEN 99
        ELSE dbo.Position.Grid_Group
    END) AS Grid_Group 
FROM dbo.USession AS us
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Position ON us.PositionId = dbo.Position.PositionId
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Sessions AS s ON us.SessionId = s.SessionId  
ORDER BY
    S.SessionNumber,
    (CASE
        WHEN dbo.Position.Grid_Group IS NULL THEN 99
        ELSE dbo.Position.Grid_Group
    END)
```

I allowed myself to apply some minor formatting of your SQL.

Comment: Thanks worked great. Both Coalesce and case in the order by provided the expected results

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. And yes `COALESCE` would be a more succint way of expressing your logic - I would recommend using that instead of the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1):

An `ORDER BY` will in this case not see your calculated columns. To get the effect you're asking for, you'll have to `ORDER BY` the same expression (which kastermester's answer is demonstrating), or wrap the query in a common table expression and `ORDER BY` while selecting from that, something like;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT s.SessionNumber, p.PositionName, COALESCE(p.Grid_Group, 99) Grid_Group 
  FROM dbo.USession AS us 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Position p ON us.PositionId = p.PositionId 
  FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Sessions s ON us.SessionId  = s.SessionId
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY SessionNumber, Grid_Group;
```